# How can I find the error for polynomial functions?

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

Is there any possibility to find the error like R-squared for linear functons?

My code:

```
df=df._get_numeric_data()

y_data = df['price']
x_data=df.drop('price',axis=1)

pr=PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)

x_train_pr=pr.fit_transform(x_train[['horsepower', 'curb-weight', 'engine-size', 'highway- 
mpg','normalized-losses','symboling']])

x_test_pr=pr.fit_transform(x_test[['horsepower', 'curb-weight', 'engine-size', 'highway- 
mpg','normalized-losses','symboling']])

RigeModel=Ridge(alpha=1)

RigeModel.fit(x_train_pr, y_train)

yhat = RigeModel.predict(x_test_pr)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I solved the problem